# Max and Min on n dimensional sphere

Tags: real-analysis

I know there a similar question already but the other example doesn't help me because it doesn't completely apply to this exercise with the following given information.
Let $x=(x_1,...,x_n)^t$. We have $f(x)=x_1\cdot x_2 \cdot ... \cdot x_n$.
We also have $S^{n-1}={x \in \mathbb{R}: x_1^2+...+x_n^2=1}$ Im trying to find the Max and Min on $S^{n-1}$ with the given information. I was trying Lagrange Multiplicators like the following.
Let $L(x,\lambda)=f(x)+ \lambda \cdot g(x)$, with $g(x)= x_1^2+...+x_n^2-1=0$
Then as usual for extreme values calculating the gradient like the following:
$\nabla L(x,\lambda)= \begin{bmatrix}
           2x_{1} \cdot x_2^2 \cdot...\cdot x_n^2+2x_1 \cdot \lambda \\
            \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{1}^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2-1
         \end{bmatrix}=0$

At this point I don't quite know how to continue.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you "know there is a similar question already" then include a link so that people do not duplicate efforts

Comment: you're right. Next time I will think of that!

Comment: @Mathman: You can edit your questions to include links, you know....

Comment: The question has been answered correctly already days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n \geq 2$.

Assuming $x \in S^{n-1}$, from first $(n-1)$ equations you can get that:

$$\forall i \in \{1, .. n\}: \,\, \lambda = -\prod \limits_{k \neq i} x_{k}^2$$

So, for each $i$ such a product is the same. Using this for arbitrary $i, j$,
we get that $x_i^2 = x_j^2$, and using the last equation, finally that:

$$\forall i \in \{1, .. n\}: \,\, x_i = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Since $f(x)$ reaches global Maximum and global Minimum on the sphere in some points, those have to appear among the list of points that satisfy $x_i = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

At the same time we have only two (opposite) values of $f(x)$ on those points. So, they ought to be global Minimum and Maximum. Therefore, all points from that list are global maximums or minimums, respectively. So, we have Max/Min values and all the local maximas/mimimas on our hands, and latter are global maximas/minimas too.

Comment: Oh thanks this makes sense to me, you helped me a lot!